# How can i make the common function/view for servinf downloadble files in django python

Tags: python, django, download

I am displaying the list of objects in the html table.
i have the download link in front of every row which i want them to download the linked file.

I have made this function

```
def make_downloadable_link(path):
    #Prepare the form for downloading
    wrapper      = FileWrapper(open(mypath))
    response     = HttpResponse(wrapper,'application/pdf')
    response['Content-Length']      = os.path.getsize(mypath)  
    fname = mypath.split('/')[-1]  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= fname'
    return response
```

This is working fine if i use it for hard coded path in view for single file. But i want to make a generic view so that it works on all the files in the table

I hav the path of the file avaiable in `object.path` variable but i am confused how can i pass the path object to the downlaod file view. because i want to hide that actual path from the user.

I don't know what to write in the URLs.py file fo that download file view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you like to do is get actual file path from object. And as you have said the file path is stored in `object.path` that makes it easy.

For example:

urls.py

```
url(r'^download/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', "yourapp.views.make_downloadable_link", name="downloadable")
```

In views.py:

```
def make_downloadable_link(object_id):

    # get object from object_id
    object = ObjectModel.objects.get(id=object_id)
    mypath = object.path

    #prepare to serve the file
    wrapper      = FileWrapper(open(mypath))
    response     = HttpResponse(wrapper,'application/pdf')
    response['Content-Length']      = os.path.getsize(mypath)  
    fname = mypath.split('/')[-1]  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= fname'
    return response
```

Comment: i tried that but django says that no url defined and also for this question. i want the file stored in some dir to serve as download not necessarily the File field